# Are there any good 3rd party libraries build on top of openCL yet?

Tags: c++, opencl, primitive

I'm thinking in particular of processing primitives, things like FFT, convolution, correlation, matrix mathematics, any kind of machine vision primitives.  I haven't been
able to find anything along these lines, does anyone know of any good projects that have sprung up?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a library per say (yet) but I've developed a bunch of matrix multiplication examples for a research project.  It contains a vectorized Matrix Multiply kernel that is faster than the example ones that NVIDA provides for OpenCL and CUDA.  It also contains a few helpful functions for running OpenCL programs, etc

The source code and project is here: https://sites.google.com/site/jhosite/parallel-systems

Answer (score 3):

I think that these kinds of libraries will be coming soon but are not yet widely available because OpenCL is so new.  That being said, Apple has released an FFT library for OpenCL:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenCL_FFT/index.html